# How to restore Postgresql without pg_control but with file system backup and wal files?

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-10

OS: Ubuntu 16.04, Docker

Postgresql: 10

I'm using [an alternative file-system backup that is making “consistent snapshot” of the data directory every 24 hours.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/backup-file.html) I'm experiencing the warning from the Postgresql documentation. See link above.

> and you are willing to trust that it is implemented correctly ...

The problem is that the files are incomplete after 1 week. For whatever reason my `pg_control` file has only been backed up for 6 days. This leads to the problem that restoring a file system backup that is older than 6 days throws an error that the `pg_control` file is missing.

A positive aspect of my backup is that I have a complete history of WAL files. So not only 6 days but endless into the past.

So my plan is to work with the copy that is 6 days old and try to replay the WAL logs until I reached my desired state. Let's work with a real dates.

My database starts just fine for the date 2019-01-27 and I now want to replay WAL files to get the database state to 2018-12-18.

---

**Prerequisite**
I copied the server files from the 2019-01-27 to a local machine where the same version of Postgresql (10) is running. The backup has been taken while Postgresql was running. Anyways as explained [in the documentation it just gives a short warning and starts fine locally](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/backup-file.html).

**Intent 1: Copy WAL files into pg_wal and start**

1. Clear the main directory: `rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/*`
2. Extract the copy that works fine. Change ownership and permissions. Remove postmaster.pid.
3. Copy all pg_wal files to pg_wal
4. As postgres user: `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin postgres -D /.../main`
5. Everything works fine.

Logs:

```
LOG: database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-01-27 20:00:00 UTC
LOG: database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG: redo starts at 1/D160878
LOG: invalid record length at 1/D160958; wanted 24, got 0
LOG: redo done at 1/D160920
LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
```

Weird for me is that the WAL files total number has been decreased inside of pg_wal.

6. Stop the server.
7. Create a recovery.conf

```
restore_command = 'cp /dir/with/all_wal_files_backup/%f "%p"'
recovery_target_time = '2018-12-18 20:00:00 UTC'
recovery_target_inclusive = false
```

8. Start the server

LOGS:

```
LOG: starting point-in-teim recovery to 2018-12-18 20:00:00+00
cp: cannot stat /dir/with/all_wal_files_backup/00010001D: No such file or dir
consisten recovery state reached at 1/D160a70
redo is not required
db is ready to accept read only connections
cp: cannot stat /dir/with/all_wal_files_backup/00010001D: No such file or dir
cp: cannot stat /dir/with/all_wal_files_backup/0002.history: No such file or dir
LOG: selected new timeline ID: 2
Archive recovery complete
cp: cannot stat /dir/with/all_wal_files_backup/0001.history: No such file or dir
db is ready to accept read only connections
```

Now when I try to select the data that I'm searching for they are not there. Where is my mistake?

I already tried to pg_basebackup and then to restore and countless of other forms but always without success so I hope that someone here can help me out.

thanks in advance

---

### Update

I tried the procedure as explained in the comment with the following result: I still can't select the data I'm expecting. Even though it tells me succes it seems like the recovery is broken. Any ideas?

```
2019-02-04 14:08:16.330 UTC [12412] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-01-27 20:04:15 UTC
2019-02-04 14:08:18.181 UTC [12412] LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2018-12-15 08:00:00+00
2019-02-04 14:08:18.181 UTC [12412] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-02-04 14:08:18.185 UTC [12412] LOG:  redo starts at 1/D160878
2019-02-04 14:08:18.185 UTC [12412] LOG:  invalid record length at 1/D160958: wanted 24, got 0
2019-02-04 14:08:18.188 UTC [12412] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 1/D160958
2019-02-04 14:08:18.188 UTC [12411] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2019-02-04 14:08:18.200 UTC [12412] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000010000000D" from archive
2019-02-04 14:08:18.242 UTC [12412] LOG:  invalid record length at 1/D160958: wanted 24, got 0
2019-02-04 14:08:18.242 UTC [12412] LOG:  redo done at 1/D160920
2019-02-04 14:08:18.266 UTC [12412] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000010000000D" from archive
cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/archivedir/00000002.history': No such file or directory
2019-02-04 14:08:18.313 UTC [12412] LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 2
2019-02-04 14:08:18.393 UTC [12412] LOG:  archive recovery complete
cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/archivedir/00000001.history': No such file or directory
2019-02-04 14:08:18.532 UTC [12411] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Answer (score 1):

> My database starts just fine for the date 2019-01-27 and I now want to replay WAL files to get the database state to 2018-12-18.

Replay only works forward, never backwards.

If pg_control were they only thing missing from your older backups, it is possible you could manually recreate a suitable copy of pg_control using a newer copy as a template.  But chances are other files are also missing.

Your situation seems hopeless.  If this data is truly precious, you should hire data-recovery professionals.  You are beyond "free help on the internet" territory.

Comment: Didn't understand this one "Replay only works forward, never backwards" until now. Thanks for the clarification. Hopefully you understand I don't mark this as the accepted answer because it doesn't solve my problem. I understood that the probability is high that is will never work. I already tried the pg_control approach but I will keep trying with different timestamps. Thank you anyway for your answer. I still have a little bit of hope ;)

Comment: When you say `using a newer copy as a template` do you mean that there is a possibility that I can manually change content of `pg_control` to somehow (almost magically with a lot of luck) match the older version or do you mean to simply take a newer 'pg_control`?

Comment: I don't know the details, but you would have to keep the "Database system identifier" the same, but change the "Latest checkpoint location" to point to a location in the WAL which is before the time the damaged backup occurred.  You would probably need to change other things as well, but I don't know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it seems like a risky and over-complicated way to perform a backup and I think Postgres documentation needs an upgrade to prevent people to go to that path... I strongly recommend you reconsider your choices.

However, when you start the server, it will perform a recovery because you copied inconsistent data. At the end of the recovery, it will perform a checkpoint (so, it means it will write data on disk and register a checkpoint occured in the WALs.)
When you stop it and restart it, it can't perform PITR in top of that because your instance is in a new "reality" (the last WAL is different as the checkpoint is recorded).

To perform PITR, you need to copy your files, add your recovery file and only then start your server.

However, I'm not sure you'll be able to do that as it seems you have corrupted WAL in your backup (`LOG: invalid record length at 1/D160958; wanted 24, got 0`).

Comment: I will try this in the afternoon and update my topic accordingly. Thank you for your proposal. Anyways I remember that this approach leads to "Invalid primary, secondary checkpoint" but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer. Similar result.

Comment: As I said that log line `invalid record length at 1/D160958: wanted 24, got 0` means you have a corrupted WAL backup. So you can't PITR after LSN 1/D160958.

Comment: Ok thanks :( Any idea why Postgres creates `00000001000000010000000D  00000002000000010000000D  00000002.history  00000003000000010000000D  00000003.history  archive_status` in pg_wal but tells me `no such file or dir` in my archivedir? If Postgresql creates those files in `pg_wal` obviously it cant find it in my `archivedir`. Might that indicate something? I don't want to accept that having a file backup and wal_files I cant restore my db. ^^

Comment: I suppose it means he promoted it so the timeline changed. I suppose it's looking for  `00000002.history` to be sure that timeline number 2 is not already taken.

Comment: Ok thanks and sorry I'm just desperate for any hint that might help me solve this problem. As I said I cant accept that having a file backup and wal_files there is no possibility of recovering the data to that date in time. Its so frustrating knowing that the data is there but not accessible ...

Comment: That's were you're wrong. What you have is inconsistent data and corrupted WAL files. Postgres don't know how to deal with that. If consistency is not such a big deal for you, maybe Postgres isn't the right choice.
Anyway, I strongly recommend that you look at pg_backrest, pg_probackup and pg_barman for your backups and recoveries.

Comment: "However, I'm not sure you'll be able to do that as it seems you have corrupted WAL in your backup (LOG: invalid record length at 1/D160958; wanted 24, got 0).".  This type of message is normal at the end of recovery, when all valid WAL has been replayed.  It only indicates corruption if you know there should be valid WAL after that point.

Comment: I hadn't paid attention enough : I haven't seen he wanted to go backward instead of forward.... That's why I thought there should be records in that WAL file...